# Object currently drawn in loop

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code, basically I need to create the pattern shown in the image

[image: pattern 1]

using the `graphics` module written by Prof John Zelle (available [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/index.html)).

Which is 10 straight lines, need to create it in different size canvas depending on what the user chooses. So i decided to loop it and adding extra space between each line, but when I execute the loop I get an error saying the line has already been drawn, anyone knows how to avoid this?

```
from graphics import *

def Main():

    valid = False
    while not valid:

        sizeInput= eval(input("PLease select a size, 7, 9, 11: "))
        if sizeInput == 7 or sizeInput == 9 or sizeInput == 11 :
            size= sizeInput*100
            valid=True

        else:
            print("Invalid Number")

    Draw(size)

def Draw(size):
    win = GraphWin("Pat1",size,size)
    PointX= Point(0,0)
    PointY= Point(700,70)

    line = Line(PointX,PointY)
    i = 0
    while i<10:
        line.draw(win)
        PointX.x+70
        PointY.y+70
        i=i+1
```

Comment: `PointX.x+70` does nothing. You want `PointX.x += 70`. Also, move `line = Line(PointX,PointY)` to the first line of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a Python neophyte myself, I tried this project. Here's what I came up with. I'm sure there's optimization to be done and error checking needs to be added, but it works.

```
from graphics import *

def Main():
    # Have user enter actual window size (ex: "500" for a 500x500 window)
    size = int(input("Please enter a window size: "))
    # Have user enter number of lines to draw
    line_count = int(input("Please enter a line count: "))

    # Create the window
    win = GraphWin("Pat1", size, size)
    # Calculate space between lines
    step = size / line_count

    # Renamed these to something more logical
    point_start = Point(0, 0)
    point_end = Point(size, step)

    # Draw top half
    for i in range(line_count):
        line = Line(point_start, point_end)
        line.draw(win) 
        point_start.x += step
        point_end.y += step

    point_start = Point(0, 0)
    point_end = Point(step, size)

    # Draw bottom half
    for i in range(line_count):
        line = Line(point_start, point_end)
        line.draw(win) 
        point_start.y += step
        point_end.x += step

Main()
```